# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, npm-start

I buy a react theme from theme forest and trying to open it I install npm and then I execute the command npm start and I get the error showing bellow. I send a message to developer he reply back and said execute the command npm install react-dev-utils --save
I try this but still getting the same error.
So can anyone help me to resolve this problem.

```
PS C:\Theme\reactjs\Template> npm start

> Artha@0.1.0 start
> node scripts/start.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

**Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin'**
Require stack:
- C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\config\webpack.config.js:16:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Theme\\reactjs\\Template\\config\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Theme\\reactjs\\Template\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

**Sometime I am getting this error**

PS C:\Theme\reactjs\Template> npm start

```
> Artha@0.1.0 start
> node scripts/start.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

**Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter'**

Require stack:
- C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Theme\reactjs\Template\config\webpack.config.js:23:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Theme\\reactjs\\Template\\config\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Theme\\reactjs\\Template\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```